# "Failed to load module script" error when building and serving with a base property in vitejs

Tags: nginx, hosting, pm2, serve, vite

I'm having an issue in serving a [`vite`](https://vitejs.dev) app. I'm building the app using the following command:

```sh
    vite build --base=/registration-form/
```

and serving the app with

```sh
    serve -s dist
```

But I'm getting the following error in the browser console and all the `.js` files are HTML files.

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html".
> Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

### More context:

I'm using serving in production with `pm2`, `serve` & `nginx`. This is my startup script:

```sh
    pm2 start "serve -s -p [PORT] dist" --name registration-form
```

and this is the part of my `nginx.conf` that handles this route:

```
    location /ideathon-registration/ {
        http://[HOST]:[PORT];
    }
```

How do I solve this?

> Vite version: ^2.3.8
> Node version: 14.17.1
> Local OS: Linux Mint 20.04
> Server OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm facing a similar issue.